# Customize QrCode Color

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, qr-code

I have been using a [Jquery Plugin](http://jeromeetienne.github.io/jquery-qrcode/) for creating QRcode.
I want to customize it by changing it's forecolor and background color. Is there any way I could do it?

Comment: Probably; what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this [jQuery.qrcode](https://larsjung.de/jquery-qrcode/) plugin.

It offers `fill` for the forecolor, and `background` for the background, and many other options to set.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to find colour codes in the file? My lucky guess - try to change them in line 433:

```
 qrHtml += _this.isDark(r, c)? '#000000' : '#ffffff';
```

For example, change

```
 #000000
```

to

```
#0000ff
```

for blue instead of black.

Answer (score 0):

valid options:

```
{
        render      : "canvas",
        width       : 256,
        height      : 256,
        typeNumber  : -1,
        correctLevel    : QRErrorCorrectLevel.H,
        background      : "#ffffff",
        foreground      : "#000000"
}
```

see https://github.com/jeromeetienne/jquery-qrcode/blob/master/src/jquery.qrcode.js#L10